# How to induce representations of quantized universal enveloping algebras

Tags: reference-request, modules, representation-theory, lie-algebras

The book Enveloping Algebras, by Jacques Dixmier has a chapter on inducing representations of universal enveloping algebras (chapter 5) and it goes very simply and smoothly: If $\mathfrak{h}$ is a Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{g}$, and $W$ is a $U(\mathfrak{h})$-module, then we can imbue $U(\mathfrak{g}) \otimes_{U(\mathfrak{h})} W$ with a $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module structure ($g` \cdot (g \otimes w) = g`g \otimes w$) called the induced moduled structure.

I need to know how this process works in the quantized case, so my question is: Do you know if there are references in the literature treating the quatized case? Of course, you can just answer this question with the induction procedure in the quantized case, but I would really appreciate references.

Comment: I would think any of the standard references for quantum groups should deal with this topic. The definition is basically the same (though as with Lie algebras, most of the treatment will focus on the Verma modules as these are the ones with the nicest properties).

Comment: I didn`t find anything on induced representations  of QUE-algebras on Kassel, Timmerman or Chari.

Comment: Do none of those at least cover Verma modules?

Comment: Chari has a very quick introduction to them, but only in the finite-dimensional module case, and nothing related to induced reps.

Comment: That does not make any sense to me. Verma modules are induced modules and they are not finite dimensional (though they are induced from finite dimensional modules).

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I`m reading some lecture notes on Verma Modules, and now I see how they are induced modules over weight reps. Chari gives the definition but doesn`t mention induction, and I didn`t connect the dots.